# CSS li should remain active when we hover on the dropdown

Tags: css, navigation, hover

I am trying to make a navigation in css but when I hover on the dropdown menu the parent `<li>` does not remain active. Please ignore the images as it will not be visible as it is on the local drive.

Please find below the code :

```
        <div class="nav"><!--nav start-->
        <ul class="icons_nav">
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/inventory_icon.png" /><span>Inventory</span></a>
             <ul class="dropdown1">
               <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Purchase</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Closing Stock</a></li>
             </ul></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/accounts_icon.png" /><span>Accounts</span></a>
             <ul class="dropdown2">
               <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Purchase</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Closing Stock</a></li>
             </ul></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/loyalty_icon.png" /><span>Loyalty Customer</span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown3">
               <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Purchase</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Closing Stock</a></li>
             </ul></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div><!--nav end-->
```

**CSS**

```
.nav {
    width:690px;
    margin:10px auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.nav > ul.icons_nav {
    list-style:none;
}
.nav > ul.icons_nav > li {
    float:left;
}
.nav > ul.icons_nav > li > a {
    color:#002d49;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:46px;
    background:#fff;
}
.nav > ul.icons_nav > li > a:hover {
    background:#002d49;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
.nav > ul.icons_nav > li > a > img {
    margin:8px 0 0 8px;
    float:left;
}
.nav > ul.icons_nav > li > a > span {
    float:left;
    margin:14px 0 0 10px;
}
.nav > ul.icons_nav > li > ul.dropdown1 {
    background:#002d49;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:690px;
    height:40px;
    position:absolute;
    margin:46px 0 0 0;
    display:none;
}
.nav > ul.icons_nav > li > ul.dropdown2 {
    background:#002d49;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:690px;
    height:40px;
    position:absolute;
    margin:46px 0 0 -230px;
    display:none;
}
.nav > ul.icons_nav > li > ul.dropdown3 {
    background:#002d49;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:690px;
    height:40px;
    position:absolute;
    margin:46px 0 0 -460px;
    display:none;
}
.nav > ul.icons_nav > li > a.active {
    background:#002d49;
}
.nav > ul.icons_nav > li > ul > li {
    float:left;
    width:230px;
}
.nav > ul.icons_nav > li > ul > li > a {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    margin:10px 0 0 20px;
    display:block;
}
.nav > ul.icons_nav > li > ul > li > a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.nav > ul.icons_nav > li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: When you say `active`, you mean that the `anchor` in the `li` should have `background:#002d49; color:#FFFFFF;}` ...??

Comment: Yes li should be active with background:#002d49;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following style in your CSS.

```
.nav > ul.icons_nav > li:hover a{background:#002d49; color:#fff;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dfzxsqpz/)

Comment: I wanted to suggest to change the hover effect on the `li` instead of the `a`, but as I was editing the code I found that it needed two extra rules and more adjustment than expected. This is the easiest solution! +1

Comment: Thank you @Suresh Ponnukalai

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this helps?

I took the background and text color change off the a:hover and added that it gets applied to the a tag on the ul:hover

```
.nav > ul.icons_nav > li:hover a {background-color:#002d49; color:#FFFFFF;}
```

In the previous code, once you hover off the parent li the anchor goes back to it's original bg color #fff

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bnxaqua4/